# SQL data comparison tool for SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server, comparison

Does anyone know of a tool similiar to RedGate's SQL Data Compare that works with Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved this problem by Exporting my 2 SQL Server Compact Databases to SQL Server Express 2005 (although 2008 would work) using [Data Port Console](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortConsole.html).

I then compared them using [Red Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm).

This solution works just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me the following process worked:

1. Install SQL [Server Compact Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/) extension.
2. Run the "Script database schema and data" command on both databases
3. Use a diff tool on generated files to see the changes.

   [image: List item]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you could also have a look at the Apex SQL tools - Apex SQL Diff and Apex SQL DataDiff. There website is [here](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.asp). They don't specifically mention SQL Server Compact - but I'm sure you could inquire with them.

Red-Gate and Apex are my #1 choices for any kind of SQL tools :-)

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SQL Compare](http://www.starinix.com/sqlcompare02.htm) from starinix? They say it supports SQL Server (All Editions) so that may include compact edition.

This software does work as I have used it (for Yukon). It's also freeware which saves worrying about licensing.

Comment: Cheers Wayne! I'll check it out and let you know.

Comment: Ok, well at least you found a resolution anyway!